# How to instruct AppEngine to keep 1 instance alive in standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, autoscaling

I have a web and mobile Flutter app with low traffic which uses a AppEngine service as backend.
I noticed from the logs that the instances get shut down automatically and the app requests start to fail.
For some weird reason, if I start to query the app from desktop browser, the AppEngine instance starts again and everything works fine.

I tried to play with scaling settings using

```
runtime: python39
env: standard
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  min_instances: 1
```

I would expect with these settings the number of instances to always be 1 but I still see the same behaviour: the app goes down when inactive.

I inspected the app and the environment I am using is `standard`.

How can I achieve a simple deployment with 1 active instance all the time?

I don't want to use any fancy scaling feature for now. The app is pretty simple and 1 instance is enough.

Comment: If you have min_instances set, it is unusual for the instance to shut down frequently (although there [can be downtime with max_instances < 4](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/troubleshooting#max-instances)).  What do your logs show when the instances shut down?  Are you seeing any errors (eg. memory limits) that are causing the instance to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable warmup requests? The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python#scaling_elements) says

> Warning: For this feature to function properly, you must make sure that warmup requests are enabled and that your application handles warmup requests.

Also, try to see if you can reduce the startup time when your App receives a new instance request by only importing libraries/initializing stuff when they're needed and not at the beginning of your module .e.g. if you're storing stuff in cloud storage, only import the cloud storage library and initialize it when you actually need to store stuff and not whenever the python file is loaded

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation 1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python#min_idle_instances), You can use `min_instance` to keep an instance alive without any traffic incoming for example if you want to keep the instance alive without having traffic for 10 minutes, then you can set the idle time for 10 minutes like this in the app.yaml file

```
runtime: python39
env: standard
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  min_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

Also you may check with `min_idle_instances`  in the [Documentation 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python#min_idle_instances:%7E:text=number%20you%27ve%20specified.-,min_idle_instances,-Warning%3A%20For) where you define how many instances you want to keep alive. These instances are kept idle and running in the background to receive traffic.

Do note that it may increase your monthly invoice as those instances are live, whether or not they are receiving traffic.

Comment: This configuration will not work, and may even fail to deploy.  idle_timeout is a basic_scaling element, not an automatic_scaling element ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python#scaling_elements)).